# Let $ S^2 = \{ (x,y,z\} \in \Bbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2 =1\}, a=(1,0,0)$ Show that $S^2$ \ $\{a\}$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ S^2 = \{ (x,y,z\} \in \Bbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2 =1\}, a=(0,0,1)$ Show that $S^2$ \ $\{a\}$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are homeomorphic.

I do not understand how $S^2$ \ $\{a\}$  is injective since still $\exists (1,0,0)$ and $ (0,1,0)$ in $S^2$

Comment: Try the stereographic projection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need direct solution for north pole. Following functions can help to you.

Hint:$f:S^2$\ $\{a\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z})$ and inverse function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2$\ $\{a\}$ such that $g(u,v)=\frac{(2u,2v,u^2+v^2-1)}{u^2+v^2+1}$.

What is the meaning of $S^2$\ $\{a\}$ injective ?

You must show that $f\circ g=1_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g\circ f=1_{S^2\backslash \{a\}}$ for bijectivity.

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically speaking, this is a stereographic projection.Imagine the sphere $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the plane   of sphere at its equator and $a$ as the north pole. Then the  take any point $b$ in the sphere.The line joining $a$ and $b$ intersects $\mathbb{R}^2$ uniquely. Thus the map is defined and it is a bijection. The rest is to show continuity and the inverse function being continuous. This is also easy. Thus it is a homemorphism.

Morever $S^2$ is called the "one-point" compactification of  $\mathbb{R}^2$.
This is generally true for $S^n$ also.